# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{n^{3/2}t}{1+n^3t^3}dt}$ using Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having trouble with the dominating function.

The book suggests:

$$\frac{n^{3/2}t}{1+n^3t^3} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$$

What should I do to prove this inequality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiply the inequality with $\sqrt{t}$. Look hard and see an $x$ and an $x^2$.

Comment: I accidentally gave an answer without reading carefully. You are supposed to show some effort or give some thoughts. The hint by @DanielFischer should lead you all the way...

Comment: If $x = (nt)^{3/2}$, then $\frac{n^{3/2}t^{3/2}}{1+n^3t^3} = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$.  
We have $(1-x)^2 = 1 -2x + x^2\ge 0 \Rightarrow 1+x^2 \ge 2x \Rightarrow \frac{x}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{x}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}$.  
Thus $\frac{n^{3/2}t^{3/2}}{1+n^3t^3} \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Thank you @DanielFischer

Comment: You're welcome. I think the way of least work to wrap it up would now be if @mickep undeletes their answer, so this question can quickly get an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $0\leq (a-b)^2$ it follows that
$$
ab\leq \frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2).
$$
With $a=1$ and $b=n^{3/2}t^{3/2}$, you get
$$
n^{3/2}t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}(n^{3/2}t^{3/2})\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}(1+n^3t^3).
$$
Now divide by $1+n^3t^3$ and you are done.